# Question about an exercise in Arbib and Manes’ text concerning coequalizer and a possible misprint.

Tags: category-theory

The following question, is taken from Arbib and Manes’ *Arrows, structures and functors* text:

> **Definition 1:**  Given an equivalence relation $E$ on a set $A$, we define the **equivalence class** of an element $a$ of $A$ with respect to $E$ to be
> $$
>   [a]_E = \{ a' \mid \text{$a'\in A$ and $(a, a') \in E$} \}
> $$
> (when no ambiguity can arise, we write $[a]$ for $[a]_E$.)  The **factor set** or **quotient set of $A$ with respect to $E$** is then the set of equivalence classes
> $$A/E = \{ [a] \mid a \in A \} \,.$$

> **Definition 2:** Given any function $f \colon A \rightarrow B$, we define the **equivalence relation $E(f)$ of $f$** on $A$ by
> $$
>   E(f) = \{ (a, a') \in A \times A \mid f(a) = f(a') \} \,.
> $$
>
> […]
>
> Given *any* relation $R$ on $A$ (i.e. any subset of $A\times A$) we may associate with it the two projection maps
> $$
>   p_k
>   \colon
>   R \rightarrow A \,,
>   \quad
>   (a_1, a_2) \mapsto a_k \,,
>   \quad
>   k = 1, 2 \,.
> $$
> On the other hand, given any pair of maps
> $$
>   p_1, p_2 \colon R \rightarrow A
> $$
> with common domain, and with codomain $A$, we may define on $A$ the corresponding relation
> $$
>   E_R = \{ (p_1(r), p_2(r)) : r \in R \subset A \times A
>   \tag{$1$}
> $$
> (where we forbear writing $E_{(R, p_1, p_2)}$ for brevity).

> **Definition 3:** We say a map $A \xrightarrow{h} B$  is a **coequalizer** if and only if there exists a pair $p_1, p_2 \colon R \rightarrow A$ of maps such that $h \circ p_1 = h \circ p_2$, and such that whenever $A \xrightarrow{h'} B'$ satisfies $h' \circ p_1 = h'\circ p_2$, there is a unique map $B \xrightarrow{\psi} B'$ such that $\psi \circ h = h'$.
>
> [image]
>
> In this situation, we call $h$ the **coequalizer** of $p_1$ and $p_2$ and write $h = \mathrm{coeq}(p_1, p_2).$

> **Exercise** Let $p_1, p_2 \colon R \rightarrow A$ be functions with disjoint images, i.e., $p_1(R) \cap p_2(R) = \emptyset$. Show that if $B$ is a $1$-element set and $h \colon A \rightarrow B$ is the unique function then $h = \mathrm{coeq}(p_1, p_2)$.  [Use Definition 3.]

For the **Exercise** above, **I would like to know** how does the unique map $h$ in the question is related to the unique map $\psi$ in **Definition 3**. Also, since $B$ is a singleton set, say $B = \{ b \}$ then, I have to make it into a relation and in turn into an equivalence relation by defining the following binary relation: $\{ (b, b) \in E \mid (b, b) \in B\}$. Also as stated in the conclusion of the exercise, if I need to show that $h = \mathrm{coeq}(p_1, p_2)$, then $h \circ p_1 = h \circ p_2$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what I understand, $h$ has no relationship to $\psi$. Rather, $h$ is the unique function to the terminal object (recall that the singleton is terminal in set).

Comment: @IsAdisplayName does this mean I will end up having two different unique functions for solving the question, if $h$ don't serve the role that $\psi$ do in **Definition 3**?

Answer (score 1):

The coequaliser arrow $h$ is not supposed to be the arrow $\psi$. They have different domains (in general) for one thing. They only say ‘unique’ because $B$ is terminal, it is not to be confused with the uniqueness of $\psi$.

You also don’t need to find a relation on $B$ (there are only two anyway, the empty one and the trivial one): notice that the *descriptive* definition of coequaliser given by your text makes *no reference at all* to relations. However when your text goes onto to proving that $\mathsf{Set}$ has all coequalisers (at least, it should do…) you will find a constructive definition involving relations.

You just need to check $h$ satisfies the universal property; $h\circ p_1=h\circ p_2$ and, for *any* $h’$, a unique $\psi$ is born*e*. ($\psi$ is inherently related to $h’$, but not really to $h$)

By the way, the exercise is false. Let $R=\{\ast\}$, $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $p_{1,2}$ defined by $p_{1,2}(\ast)=1,2$ respectively. These have disjoint images. Suppose $h:A\to\{b\}$ is really a coequaliser. Consider $h’:A\to\{0,1\}$ the function $0\mapsto0,1\mapsto1,2\mapsto1$. Then $h’\circ p_1=h’\circ p_2$ but, since $h’$ is not constant, it is completely impossible for $h’$ to factor through $B=\{b\}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141570/discussion-on-answer-by-fshrike-question-about-an-exercise-in-arbib-and-manes-t).

Comment: @FShrike  In this question  it is given to you.  If it is not given to you, i think both author says that you define the smallest equivalence relation, say $E$ on the binary relation on $A$ so constructed, then you have a map $h$ that sends $E$ to $A/E$ as $b\mapsto [b]$, where $[b]\in A/E$.  After, define  the unique map $q([b[)=h(b)$. to show that it is unique.